# For type hinting purposes, what are the advantages of np.typing.NDArrray over np.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, python-typing

If we check the source of numpy, we will find in [numpy/__init__.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/__init__.pyi#L1477) that `ndarray` is declared as

```
class ndarray(_ArrayOrScalarCommon, Generic[_ShapeType, _DType_co])
```

and in [numpy/_typing/_array_like.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/_typing/_array_like.py#L30) that `NDArray` is defined as

```
NDArray = ndarray[Any, dtype[_ScalarType_co]]
```

It seems that `NDArray` is a partially specialized version of `ndarray`, which means for `ndarray` we can write `x: ndarray[(2, 2), np.float32] = ...` and `y: ndarray[np.float32] = ...` but for `NDArray` we can only write `z: NDArray[np.float32] = ...` and cannot add the shape information.

So is `NDArray` necessary?

Comment: in the future, you should tag all python-related questions with the generic [python] tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a convenience. You *can* write:

```
y: ndarray[np.float32] = ...
```

You could *also* write:

```
y: "banana" = ...
```

And that would *run* just fine, but static analysis tools would complain for *both*. Because both of those are correct type annotations. Here is an example, let's create a python script, `test_typing.py`:

```
(py311) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ cat test_typing.py
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

arr: np.ndarray[np.float64] = np.array([1,2,3],dtype=np.float64)
arr2:  npt.NDArray[np.float64] = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float64)
```

Now, let's see how `mypy` feels about it:

```
(py311) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ mypy test_typing.py
test_typing.py:4: error: "ndarray" expects 2 type arguments, but 1 given  [type-arg]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

So, as you can see, it accepted the second one, but not the first, because the first one is not a valid annotation.

And just for good measure, `pyright` (another very popular static type checker) also complains:

```
(py311) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ pyright test_typing.py
No configuration file found.
No pyproject.toml file found.
Assuming Python platform Darwin
Searching for source files
Found 1 source file
pyright 1.1.304
/Users/jarrivillaga/test_typing.py
  /Users/jarrivillaga/test_typing.py:4:17 - error: Too few type arguments provided for "ndarray"; expected 2 but received 1 (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
1 error, 0 warnings, 0 informations
Completed in 1.397sec
```

Comment: Right. Or I will have to write `arr: np.ndarray[typing.Any, np.dtype[np.float64]]`.

Comment: It's a *parameterized type alias*: `NDArray = ndarray[Any, dtype[_ScalarType_co]]`. Ok, consider an example outside of numpy, Suppose I wanted a type alias for "a pair of things where the first is a string": `Pair = tuple[str, T]` (where `T` is a type variable). Then I can do things like `x: Pair[int] = "foo", 1`, note what `print(Pair[int], Pair[str])` gives you

Comment: Thanks. I understood so I deleted my comment. To those who are confused, I was asking something like "What makes type checkers accept `NDArray` but not `ndarray`, given that `NDArray` is simply an assignment `NDArray = ndarray[Any, dtype[_ScalarType_co]]`?".